# Python 2.7: Saving excel .xls file with current date in the same folder

Tags: python-2.7

Is there any way to save excel(.xls) file with current date ?
I am using Python 2.7
I tried with following code, but it did not work. I am using **import datetime** Library.

```
import datetime
wb.save('Name of File' + datetime.datetime.now() + '.xls')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
'file1'+now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")+'.xls'
```

this thing to generate the file name with current time stamp and save the file in excel.